# Themes in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: themes

I am newbie in Ubuntu and tried to customize from usual them. At first it was like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhdEz.jpg) and I love it, but then I did something and it 
[become this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDtHL.png). 
How can I undo or change theme or at least what i did?

Comment: You might have fiddled with the Scale slider in Displays. Other then that, it look quite good, ...and definitely customized to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Ubuntu Tweak to manage your themes and icons.

You can install by downloading the deb [here](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), as the PPA doesn't seem be working on 15.10.